# Firefox: box mode?

Tags: firefox, mode

What is the "box mode" (for a lack of a better word) in
Firefox? How can I exit it again?

If I hold down the Ctrl key and left click while the 
cursor is over some element on a page it becomes boxed:

[image]

Firefox seems to go into some special mode. What is this mode for? How can I go back to normal mode?

Installed add-ons in Firefox:

- BetterPrivacy 1.29
- NoScript 1.9.0.6
- SQLite Manager 0.4.7
- (Microsoft .NET Framework Assistent 1.0 is disabled.)

Platform:

- Firefox 3.0.6
- Windows XP 64 bit SP2
- 8GB RAM

Comment: I have never seen that in Firefox. Does it frequently happen? Did it start with version 3? Maybe you could try installing Firefox 3.5

Comment: OK, I found out how to enter the box mode. I have updated the questiion accordingly.

Comment: seems you got 2 up vote by accident too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're selecting everything within the box. It's used for copying and pasting, as well as printing.

You'll find that if you now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (or use the Copy entry on the Edit menu) and then paste into another application, then everything within the border will be copied.

Similarly if you go to the File -> Print  and then click the Selection box, only the part of the page that you've selected will print out. This is a great way of saving paper when you need to print some information from a page that's covered in adverts, etc. that you'd rather not print out.

Comment: that is totally awesome.

Comment: cool. i did not know about it.

Comment: That's a great tip for FF users. I didn't even know what that was until now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any add-ons installed in Firefox? This looks like something that Firebug would do.

Comment: I have updated the question with the installed add-ons.